# Function to impact a parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
function validateForm() {
    var result = ''
    $.get(
        '/auth_validate_username/', 
        { 'result': result }, 
        function(data) {
            if (data!=='') {
                // make function validateForm return false
            }
        }
    );
};
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do something in my condition that will apply to the function above the `get` request.

What I want to do exactly is that if my condition is met in my get request, then the function `validateForm()` return false.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

EDIT:
Here is what I tried

js:

```
   var validateResult;    

   $('#but_id').click(function(event){

    validateForm().done(function(){       

     if(!validateResult)
         event.preventDefault();
   });
   })

  function validateForm() {
    var result = ''

   return $.get(
     '/auth_validate_username/', 
     { 'result': result }, 
     function(data) {
        if(data!==''){

      validateResult = false;
     }
     }
     );    
    };
```

html:

```
 <form  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

    <input id='username' type="text" name="username"/>

<button type="submit" id='but_id'>Submit</button>

     </form>
```

Comment: Whats the point? You can simply right `return false;`. Is there anything else you need?

Comment: I wan't to return false if the condition is met. Else I wan't the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to do something like this:

```
if (validateForm()) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    displayError();
}
```

Instead, simply do this:

```
function validateForm(){
  //...
  $.get(
    '/auth_validate_username/', 
    { 'result': result }, 
    success: function(data) {
      doSomething();
    },
    error: function(data) {
      displayError();
    }
  );
}
```

You just have to make sure that your server responds accordingly. I.e., your server shouldn't be generating a successful `200` response for every request to `/auth_validate_username`.

`$.get` is just a shorthand for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Read more about the callbacks in the docs.

---

#### Per your comment!

```
function doSomething(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $('form').submit();
}
function displayError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ ... }
function validateForm(event){
  $.ajax(
    url: '/auth_validate_username/',
    data: {"result": result},
    success: doSomething,
    error: displayError
  );
  return false; // prevent default form submit
}
$('form').submit(validateForm);
```

It would've been nice to know this was your goal from the start.

Comment: I think he wants it to return `false` because he has `onclick="validateForm()"` in his submit button or onsubmit event in the form.

Comment: @Juhana Exactly! What I wan't to do is to submit if data==='' and don't submit if data!==.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just don't get how I ask my form not to be submitted if I have an error. Could you help me understand that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using done with your function call.

*In html*

```
<input type ="button" id="yourButtonId" value="submit" />
```

*In javascript*

```
var validateResult;    

$('#yourButtonId').click(function(event){

   validateForm().done(function(){       
         //your code      
         if(!validateResult)
             event.preventDefault();
    });
})

function validateForm() {
  var result = ''

  return $.get(
    '/auth_validate_username/', 
    { 'result': result }, 
    function(data) {
        if(data!==''){
    // make function validateForm return false
          validateResult = false;
    }
    }
  );    
};
```

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, so nice of you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined

Comment: @Marcolac Thats because `validateForm` should return the *promise* from the `$.get` call. e.g. `return $.get( ...`

Comment: I have updated my answer and add return before $get, check it now.

Comment: You have to return false to stop submit. Did you do that?

Comment: Ok, but where do I have to return false? In the .done function?

Comment: From the event which is causing submit, I have updated my code and use event.preventDefault to stop submit.

Comment: Do you get the updated value of validateResult in done function ?

Comment: I don't know. I try to put alert(validateResult) in validateForm().done, but the popup doesn't appear. It looks like the function validateForm().done is not even taken into account.

Comment: You need to debug the code to see what point it is failing you may use debugger for it.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax will complete after the function completes. So there is no way to do what you are looking for. Re-arrange your design or submit the form from the success function in the get.

Here is my <strike>crazy</strike> approach at a workaround

```
var validating = false;
var safeSubmit = false;
function validateForm()
{
 validating = true;
 $("#formElementId").ajaxStop(function () {
  if( !validating ) return;
  if( safeSubmit ) $(this).submit();
  validating = false;
  $(this).unbind("ajaxStop");
 });
 var result = ''
 $.get(
    '/auth_validate_username/', 
    { 'result': result }, 
    function(data) {
        if (data!=='') {
            // make function validateForm return false
        }else{
          safeSubmit = true;
          //this could also simply be
          //$("#formElementId").submit();
        }
    }
 );
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Yikes! Imagine having this type of workaround every time you needed to work with asynchronous requests!

Comment: @maček - I never said it was pretty! :P I would not suggest taking these types of approaches, as form submission should be handled in a more OOP manner. I prefer `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sync call may implement what you want with 'async: false' when start a ajax call.
Tried in Chrome console and works.

```
function validateForm() {
  var result = ''
  var retval=true;

  $.ajax(
    '/auth_validate_username/', 
    {
      async: false,
      data: { 'result': result }
    }
  ).done(function ( data ){
    if(data !== ''){
      retval = false;
    }
  });
  return retval;
};
```